# Request compiler to print warning/error once when encountered (and not multiple times)?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, clang, compiler-warnings

Is it possible to instruct GCC/Clang to print a warning or error once when its encountered in a header or source file?

I went through the GCC [man(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) pages, but I did not see the feature. `-fdiagnostics-show-location=once` appears to be close, but it looks like a feature for brevity (the message is still emitted, its just shorter than a normal message).

I'm especially interested in Clang and its sanitizers. That is, I'd like Clang to warning me about undefined behavior once per offending line (when using `-fsanitize=undefined`). I'm looking at an offending library, and the redirected output is over 2GB because the same message gets printed over and over due to macro expansion from a header file.

Is there a switch to instruct GCC or Clang to warn or error once when its enountered the first time?

Comment: Maybe your best bet is to declare the offending header as a "System Header" and thus have the warnings suppressed? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html -- however that might end up resulting in fewer warnings than you asked for. It would help if you pasted the actual offending macro to get a better idea of options available

Comment: Another would be to rewrite the macro as an inline function (-- you can probably split any macro into a series of inline functions; if there are concatenations then just make sure your inline function can deal with them)